# gammu working on one PI3 but not another PI3

Tags: gammu

I have two Raspberry PI 3 machines:

- raspberrypi01
- raspberrypi05

with a ZTE MF112 USB card and a UK 3 SIM.

The "05" PI3 works fine but the "01" PI1 doesnt work at all.  See the output of the commands below:

```
pi@raspberrypi01:/tmp $ sudo gammu identify
Device               : /dev/ttyUSB1
Manufacturer         : ZTE CORPORATION
Model                : unknown (MF112)
Firmware             : BD_P671A2V1.0.2B05
IMEI                 : 864592000347386
SIM IMSI             : 234200208677663
pi@raspberrypi01:/tmp $ sudo gammu monitor 1
Press Ctrl+C to break...
Entering monitor mode...

Enabling info about incoming SMS    : No error.
Enabling info about incoming CB     : No error.
Enabling info about calls           : No error.
Enabling info about USSD            : No error.
SIM phonebook        :   0 used, 250 free
Dialled numbers      :  10 used,   0 free
Received numbers     :   0 used,  10 free
Missed numbers       :   0 used,  10 free
Own numbers          :   1 used,   5 free
Phone phonebook      :   0 used, 100 free
Battery level        : 100 percent
Charge state         : powered from battery
Signal strength      : -109 dBm
Network level        : 6 percent
SIM SMS status       : 0 used, 0 unread, 30 locations
Phone SMS status     : 3 used, 0 unread, 100 locations
Network state        : not logged into network
Packet network state : not logged into network
GPRS                 : detached

Leaving monitor mode...
pi@raspberrypi01:/tmp $ sudo gammu networkinfo
Network state        : not logged into network
Packet network state : not logged into network
GPRS                 : detached
pi@raspberrypi01:/tmp $
```

Trying to send a text message on the one above gives this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi01:~ $ echo "Test from HA" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT 05555555555
If you want break, press Ctrl+C...
Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..error 500, message reference=-1
Unknown error.
```

But this one works:

```
pi@raspberrypi05:~ $ sudo gammu identify
Device               : /dev/ttyUSB1
Manufacturer         : ZTE CORPORATION
Model                : unknown (MF112)
Firmware             : BD_P671A2V1.0.2B05
IMEI                 : 864592000347386
SIM IMSI             : 234200208677663
pi@raspberrypi05:~ $ sudo gammu monitor 1
Press Ctrl+C to break...
Entering monitor mode...

Enabling info about incoming SMS    : No error.
Enabling info about incoming CB     : No error.
Enabling info about calls           : No error.
Enabling info about USSD            : No error.
SIM phonebook        :   0 used, 250 free
Dialled numbers      :  10 used,   0 free
Received numbers     :   0 used,  10 free
Missed numbers       :   0 used,  10 free
Own numbers          :   1 used,   5 free
Phone phonebook      :   0 used, 100 free
Battery level        : 100 percent
Charge state         : powered from battery
Signal strength      : -113 dBm
Network level        : 0 percent
SIM SMS status       : 0 used, 0 unread, 30 locations
Phone SMS status     : 3 used, 0 unread, 100 locations
Network state        : home network
Network              : 234 20 (Three, United Kingdom), LAC 79, CID D6C8F0
Name in phone        : "3 UK"
Packet network state : home network
Packet network       : 234 20 (Three, United Kingdom), LAC 79, CID D6C8F0
Name in phone        : "3 UK"
GPRS                 : attached

Leaving monitor mode...
pi@raspberrypi05:~ $ sudo gammu networkinfo
Network state        : home network
Network              : 234 20 (Three, United Kingdom), LAC 79, CID D6C8F0
Name in phone        : "3 UK"
Packet network state : home network
Packet network       : 234 20 (Three, United Kingdom), LAC 79, CID D6C8F0
Name in phone        : "3 UK"
GPRS                 : attached
```

This one works fine:

```
pi@raspberrypi05:~ $ echo "Test from HA" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT 05555555555
If you want break, press Ctrl+C...
Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..OK, message reference=56
pi@raspberrypi05:~ $
```

The content of the "/root/.gammurc" on both is:

```
[gammu]

port = /dev/ttyUSB1
model = at
connection = at115200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = /tmp/gammu.log
logformat = textalldate
use_locking = yes
gammuloc =
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first device is not trying to connect to network. This can have few reasons:

- It is waiting for PIN, you can check this using `gammu getsecuritystatus`.
- It is not configured to connect to network, it's problem with some ZTE devices, Gammu can turn this, but your model was not recognized so far (I've fixed this in [9740d70](https://github.com/gammu/gammu/commit/9740d701643784e321de6533ebe5c062a4db9893)).
- There is some other problem with SIM card, does it work in other device?